# Transmission Fluid Change - High Mileage Vehicle

Tags: honda, automatic-transmission, odyssey, transmission-fluid

Should I replace the ATF in a 2007 Honda Odyssey w/ 208,841 miles?

Numerous shops advise against drain/ refill. I last changed @ 144k & was advised not to do it ascI could encounter transmission problems as a result.  The car has been maintained and no transmission slippage or problems to date

Comment: If it isn't recommended in the owner's manual I wouldn't. My car's manual specifically says the transmission is a "sealed unit" and the fluid should never be changed. Since you do have pretty high miles, I'd suggest calling Honda and asking what they think. If you used the factory ATF the first time, you're probably OK.

Comment: What is ascl stand for?

Comment: @DucatiKiller - I think it's supposed to be "as I" ... the "c" was probably a fat finger.

Comment: now it makes sense   ty

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm voting to close this as primarily opinion based. It is really up to you. If you've kept *pretty much* on schedule (changed at ~70k, then again at ~144k) you'd be due and you probably wouldn't run into an issue. I would think a regular drain and change of filter would not cause you issues. A reverse flush on the transmission probably would cause you issue (this is the type you see done at most tire shops and quickie oil change places).

Comment: The common opinion that changing transmission fluid that has been in the unit for many miles will result in unit failure is, in my experience, a myth. In thirty years and thousands of fluid changes we have experienced only one unit failure and it was already showing symptoms. One caution, these were all Japanese makes. In the Honda units of the type in question, the failures are caused by bearing and feedpipe failures. New fluid will not worsen these failures and might slow down the wear rate. Conversely, changing fluid in a unit with clutch slip symptoms does not change the symptoms.